# Paging in Advantage Database

Tags: sql, paging, advantage-database-server

i'm creating a web app that's running on an Advantage Database server, not my personal weapon of choice but that's what the company uses. 
I have a couple of big lists that the end-users need to be able to view however i can't seem to find a way to page through the results in SQL.

Is there something like LIMIT / OFFSET for Advantage Database? If no, any suggestions on approaching this?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand that LIMIT and a ROWNUM will be new features in an upcoming version of Advantage.
http://feedback.advantagedatabase.com/forums/2671-general/suggestions/30213-return-query-specific-row-number-?ref=title

However, until then, I have used this in the past to select row 50-60.

select top 10 * from mytable
where rowid not in (select top 50 rowid from mytable)

@tommieb75, you indicated that the SQL dialect was not standard.  I have found that it is based on the standards containing most of the SQL-92 standard and some of the SQL-2003 features.

Comment: this seems to work, allthough i must say it takes less time to fetch the entire table (which has around 160K records) then it takes to get a certain page out of it. also, how does this work on joined tables?

Answer (score 3):

Updating this for any stumbling here, but as Edgar mentioned in his answer, Advantage 10 SQL now supports a `START AT` keyword.

```
SELECT TOP 10 START AT 11 * FROM emp
```

See: [devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/master_limiting_query_results.htm](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/master_limiting_query_results.htm)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage9.1/select.htm), the correct syntax for `LIMIT` in Advantage is `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM YOURTABLE`.

Comment: @dries.hoebeke : Yes, apparently there is no `ROWNUM` function so having the ability to use `SELECT TOP` gets you nowhere in terms of paging. I guess your only remaining choice is to load everything into memory and do your paging logic. It's definitely a solution of maximum suckage, but I don't really see that you have other options. If you haven't already, you should probably vote for the future implementation of `ROWNUM` here: http://feedback.advantagedatabase.com/forums/2671-general/suggestions/30213-return-query-specific-row-number-